# I pressed something on my keyboard, now I'm receiving a syntax error for my with statement that was working perfectly beforehand

Tags: python, syntax

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import datetime

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate',120)  #75 words per minute
engine.setProperty('volume',0.9) #loudness of speaker

def getTime():
    str((datetime.datetime.now())

with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

myInput = r.recognize_google(audio)

responses = {"hello":"hello there", "thanks":"don't mention it", "time":getTime}

if myInput in responses.keys():
    engine.say(responses[myInput])
    engine.runAndWait()

else:
    engine.say("Sorry I don't understand that")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Hey guys, I'm really new to python and was just messing about making this. It was all running smoothly until I went to hit CTRL + Z on my keyboard to undo something. I'm pretty sure I missed the Z, and ever since then I'm getting a syntax error for the with statement.

Any idea on what the hell I've done?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Just realised I had a parenthesis missing on the getTime line